# For Loop inside Subscribe Loops Forever

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have the following code which goes into loop forever for my 150 records. What am I doing wrong here???

```
this.getData.getUsers().snapshotChanges().subscribe((usersRes) => {
let c: any = [];
        c = usersRes.map(c => ({ key: c.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
        if (c.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if (c[i].uid != this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid) {
              let friend = { $key: c[i].uid, ...c[i] };
              console.log("Inside For: " + i);
              this.addOrUpdateFriend(friend);
            }
          }
        } else {
          this.friends = [];
        }
      });
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your function?

Comment: @maury844 This function is for chat functionality to load all the app users for Create New Group page.

Comment: Why do you need the `getUsers()` subscription to be inside the other One? maybe I'm not seeing it but I can't find a variable that you get from the first subscription that you use on the second one

Comment: Thats right. I tried keeping both the subscribe events separate instead of nested but still the for loop inside second subscribe keeps on looping through my 150 records.

Comment: provide a working snippet

Comment: How do I provide a working snippet? This is one of the code from the ionic chat app I am building. Please help.

Comment: `Inside Subscribe
new-group.page.ts:71 Inside For: 0
new-group.page.ts:71 Inside For: 1
new-group.page.ts:71 Inside For: 2
new-group.page.ts:71 Inside For: 3....
new-group.page.ts:64 Inside Subscribe
new-group.page.ts:71 Inside For: 0
new-group.page.ts:71 Inside For: 1
new-group.page.ts:71 Inside For: 2
new-group.page.ts:71 Inside For: 3.. it goes on forever`

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out why your subscription is being called multiple times, I'm not familiar with how `firebase` does this, but the scenario that should work for you is the following:

1. You call your function/api to get the list of users, and this returns the list but **ONLY ONCE**.
2. You loop through the users that are not the current one and add them as friends
3. You check every now and then (maybe each 5, 10, 30 mins or so) or even better, you emit an event every time a new user is added which all the users in the "chatroom" subscribe to and update their lists of friends.

The issue with your code as it stands is that firebase is "emitting" values for the list of users multiple times, therefore you keep re-entering that block of code and your loop never stops.